# Dotnet Core publish to IIS from Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, iis, docker, .net-core

I want to publish my dotnet core app to IIS from mac. I use **VS code** for code writing and **Dotnet Core 1.1** for publishing to local directory. (for example: *bin/release/publish*). There are compiled my files, ready to copy to IIS. On my IIS I currently have installed **web deploy 3.6** and this is my VPS machine. Is there elegant way, how to copy files? The another way is using **docker**, but in this case I have the same problem. Generated docker file with *docker publisher tool* and I need to copy from **mac os**.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is no solid tooling yet, cross compilation is also troublesome. Once VS for Mac is ready I think it would be solved. Before that you should switch to Windows and publish from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Visual studio for Mac is ready, but without publish. It looks like, you can publish only to azure. Maybe, I can try it with gulp-rsync for now.

Comment: @LexLi So, VS for Mac really not support publish for now.

Comment: it is not. Compared to VS, VS for Mac has a long way to go (why it is a Preview). But Microsoft/Xamarin 's next milestone would be it after shipping VS2017.

Comment: Not sure about VS Code but VS for Mac now has a publish to folder functionality. Publish to IIS is still pending though. You can track it's update from 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351842/have-the-ability-to-publish-to-disk-and-or-ftp-not.html

Answer (score 8):

From a terminal window navigate to the folder where your .csproj file is. From there run 'dotnet publish -c release'. A folder called publish will be created in bin/Release/netcoreappX.X. You can copy those files to the appropriate directory on your server. If you need help setting up IIS, follow the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis

You can also run 'dotnet publish -h' to see all of the different arguments you can pass to the publish command.

Comment: The original post made it pretty clear that they were already able to publish to a local folder. They were asking about the next step: an elegant way to copy the files to the IIS server, such as using Web Deploy.

Answer (score 4):

[Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) (msdeploy.exe) seems to work in [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable), at least in WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). The tricky part is to extract the msi package somehow, which you can do easily on a Windows machine (you'll find the files in *C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3*).

Once you install Mono and obtain msdeploy.exe, just call the command, e.g.

```
mono msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath=/mnt/c/Data -dest:contentPath=test,ComputerName=https://example.com:8172/msdeploy.axd,UserName=WDeployAdmin,Password=PASSWORD,IncludeAcls=False,AuthType=Basic -enableRule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -verbose -allowUntrusted:true
```

This lets you sync/copy the contents of */mnt/c/Data* with the *test* web site in IIS on example.com with Web Deploy enabled.