# Deploy website to IIS from linux build agent

Tags: asp.net-core, jenkins, iis, deployment, webdeploy

### Problem description

I have a jenkins master that uses a linux build agent to build my ASP.NET Core websites using official MS linux docker containers.

I previously used a windows VM with the necessary tooling installed to build these projects and used MSDeploy.exe to deploy the sites to an IIS webserver. For this deployment I created a web package.

In my linux docker container I obviously can't use MSDeploy.exe.

### Question

How can I savely deploy an ASP.NET Core website to an IIS webserver from a linux docker container?

MSDeploy.exe connects to the IIS using a local IIS Users credentials, shutsdown the app, replaces all files that are also present in the new package, so it not just replaces the files but also does some safety settings around the actual replacement.

### Misc

I've found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303257/can-i-deploy-net-application-to-iis-from-linux), but unfortunately no real answer was found there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575431/dotnet-core-publish-to-iis-from-mac

Comment: This link should help you: [Deploy an ASP.NET container to a container registry using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/hosting-web-apps-in-docker?view=vs-2022) and [Publish to a Linux Production Environment](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, with @LexLi link I guess I could go the mono route to have msdeploy up and running inside my linux docker container used for building the app. Is there no other alternative? As with this approach I would have to install mono inside the container and provide the msdeploy.exe to it, that seems kinda cumbersome.

Comment: @samwu Sorry, but I don't see how the links you provided help me with my problem, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You can also open a support ticket for this: https://support.microsoft.com

Comment: This GitHub issue also provides some discussion regarding this, but unfortunately no solution: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/583